# Laravel 8 HTTP Put With Attach

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm creating crud API with laravel 8 as a server and it works perfectly when tested by talend/postman (running on 127.0.0.1:8000).

then i'm creating crud apps with laravel 8 as a client. everything works fine but update data with attach file.

i've try with no attach file and works

`$response = Http::put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/memo/'.$id_memo, $input);`

but, its not works when using attach file

```
$input['id_user']       = $request->id_user;
$input['date_memo']     = $request->date_memo;
$input['time_memo']     = $request->time_memo;
if ($request->hasFile('lampiran_memo')) {
    
    $lampiran_memo = $request->file('lampiran_memo');
    $nama_lampiran = $lampiran_memo->getClientOriginalName();
    $lampiran_memo->move("memo", $nama_lampiran);
    
    $thefile = fopen("memo/".$nama_lampiran, 'r');

    $response = Http::attach('lampiran_memo', $thefile)->put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/memo/14', $input);
}
```

Comment: can you please put what is `$thefile`

Comment: @KamleshPaul I've modify the question with full of code

Comment: `$lampiran_memo` it is a already `File` object don't need to `fopen` just pass `$lampiran_memo` in `Http`

Comment: @KamleshPaul i've modify the script 
```$response = Http::attach('lampiran_memo', "memo/".$filename)->put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/memo/14', $input);```


but get QueryException from API

```QueryException 

    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_pengguna' cannot be null (SQL: update `memo` set `id_pengguna` = ?, `tanggal_memo` = ?, `jam_memo` = ?, `judul_memo` = ?, `deskripsi_memo` = ?, `memo`.`updated_at` = 2021-11-12 05:22:26 where `id_memo` = 14)```

Answer (score 0):

after stuct, finally I use attach and post (not put) and works fine.

```
    $input['id_user']       = $request->id_user;
    $input['date_memo']     = $request->date_memo;
    $input['time_memo']     = $request->time_memo;
    if ($request->hasFile('lampiran_memo')) {
        
        $lampiran_memo = $request->file('lampiran_memo');
        $nama_lampiran = $lampiran_memo->getClientOriginalName();
        $lampiran_memo->move("memo", $nama_lampiran);
        
        $thefile = fopen("memo/".$nama_lampiran, 'r');
    
        $response = Http::attach('lampiran_memo', $thefile)->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updatememo', $input);

}
```